# How can I write a for loop in a more elaborative and efficient and pythonic way

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to write this for loop in a more elaborative and in a efficient way...is there a way to do that

```
for index in indices:
        x = seq[lowerIndex:(index+1)] #lower index is set to 0 so it will take the first broken string and also the last string
        digests.append(x) #it will add the pieces here in to a given list format 
        print("length: "+ str(len(x)) + " range: " + str(lowerIndex + 1) + "-" + str(index+1)) #This will print the length of each piece and how long each piece is. 
        print(x) #this will print the piece or fragments
        lowerIndex = index + 1 # this refers to the piece after the first piece
```

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Post [mre], incl. sample input and expected output. What is this code supposed to do anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
# new indices contains the beginning index of all segments
indices = [i+1 for i in indices]
indices.insert(0, 0)

for from, to in zip(indices, indices[1:]):  # pair 2 consecutive indices
    x = seq[from:to]
    digest.append(x)
    print(f'length: {to-from} range: {from+1} - {to}')  # use string format
    print(x)
```

For example:

```sh
>>> seq = 'abcdefghijk'
>>> indices = [0, 3, 5, 6, 9]
---------- (result)
length: 3 range: 1 - 3
abc 
length: 2 range 4 - 5
de
length: 1 range 6 - 6
f
length: 3 range 7 - 9
ghi
```

Comment: But if if there are any middle strings for example if there are 3 pieces and 2 cutting sites there will be string in the middle. then to get that piece and to identify its length and range I have the following code but how can we modify the following code into as you have answered above                                                                                                         if lowerIndex+1 < lenSeq:
        s = sq[lowerIndex:lenSq]
        digests.append(s)
        print("length: "+ str(len(s)) + " range: " + str(lowerIndex + 1) + "-" + str(lenSq))